# How to get first item from array in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the following response from a POST request:

> {"facilities":[{"id":"f966a7d9-6a2d-43df-8cbf-ebdcb8c7fdc4","description":"luovbfvwofgdrcwvqtyqohjioocszgplcjh","hasAnyPartnership":false,"hasAnyProcedure":false}

So I used the "Convert String to JSON" function and got the following response:

> {'facilities': [{'id': 'f966a7d9-6a2d-43df-8cbf-ebdcb8c7fdc4',
> 'description': 'luovbfvwofgdrcwvqtyqohjioocszgplcjh',
> 'hasAnyPartnership': False, 'hasAnyProcedure': False}

How do I get the ID value that is inside FACILITIES?

'facilities': [{'id': '**f966a7d9-6a2d-43df-8cbf-ebdcb8c7fdc4**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON example you have provided is not the valid one. It is missing `]` of `facilities` array and `}` of opening external brace. After correction it should look like this  -

```
{"facilities":[{"id":"f966a7d9-6a2d-43df-8cbf-ebdcb8c7fdc4","description":"luovbfvwofgdrcwvqtyqohjioocszgplcjh","hasAnyPartnership":false,"hasAnyProcedure":false}]}
```

You can use following keywords from `JSONLibrary`

```
${json}=        Convert String to JSON      ${JsonVar}
${idValue}=     Get Value From Json     ${json}         $.facilities[0].id
```

**Output** -

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it worked here.

But now, is there any way to remove the [ ] and ' ' so that I only have the value?

Comment: `log to console  ${idValue}[0]` Do add this line and it will give you the content. Basically it is list and you can access the elements of list using index

Comment: I did it that way and it returned right: ${PARTNER_ID[0]}. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jeferson Olsson you might want mark the answer accepted. :)